# JSON structure for extjs tree mode

Tags: json, extjs

I would like to make JSON in such a way that it will work in Extjs tree, it will help to make it simple for editing.

```
{ 
name: '.',

department: [{
    name:'Basic Ext Layouts',
    expanded: false,
    Maths:[{
        name:'Absolute',
        id:'absolute',
        leaf:true,
    },{
        name:'Accordion',
        id:'accordion',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Anchor',
        id:'anchor',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Border',
        id:'border',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Card (TabPanel)',
        id:'card-tabs',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Card (Wizard)',
        id:'card-wizard',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Column',
        id:'column',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Fit',
        id:'fit',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Table',
        id:'table',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'vBox',
        id:'vbox',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'hBox',
        id:'hbox',
        leaf:true
    }]
},{
    name:'Custom Layouts',
    bilology:[{
        name:'Center',
        id:'center',
        leaf:true,
    },{
    name:'Custom Layouts 2',
    zoology:[{
        name:'Center',
        id:'left',
        leaf:true
    }]},{
    name:'Custom Layouts 3',
    botony:[{
        name:'Center',
        id:'right',
        leaf:true
    }]}]
},{
    name:'Combination Examples',
    English:[{
        name:'Absolute Layout Form',
        id:'abs-form',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Tabs with Nested Layouts',
        id:'tabs-nested-layouts',
        leaf:true
    }]
}]
}
```

Please help

Comment: Did you check ExtJS documentation? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.tree.TreePanel

Comment: Yes, I did a lot of r&d, but didnt get result. I need the js code, which will create tree in this format. I want to give names of deoartment instead of just root as a"children:" node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how your json should look like for tree panel:

```
{ text: 'Maths', id: 'mathDept', children: [
        { text:'X1', id: 'x1', leaf: true },
        { text:'X2', id: 'x2', leaf: true}
    ]
},
{ text: 'Biology', id: 'bioDept', children: [
        { text: 'Y1', id: 'y1', leaf: true},
        { text: 'Y2', id: 'y2', leaf: true}
    ]
},  
{ text: 'English', id: 'engDept',  children: [
        { text: 'Z1', id: 'z1', leaf: true},
        { text: 'Z2', id: 'z2', leaf: true},
        { text: 'Z3', id: 'z3', leaf: true}             
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to rename the children node to Department specific node like:

{ text: 'Maths', id: 'mathDept', Maths: [
        { text:'X1', id: 'x1', leaf: true },
        { text:'X2', id: 'x2', leaf: true}
    ]
},
{ text: 'Biology', id: 'bioDept', Biology: [
        { text: 'Y1', id: 'y1', leaf: true},
        { text: 'Y2', id: 'y2', leaf: true}
    ]
},  
{ text: 'English', id: 'engDept',  English: [
        { text: 'Z1', id: 'z1', leaf: true},
        { text: 'Z2', id: 'z2', leaf: true},
        { text: 'Z3', id: 'z3', leaf: true}             
    ]
}

Comment: I think its not impossible. How @Abdel wrote is the only possiblity.

Comment: I want to give different child name to each node in json, how to implement it is js file.

{ 
name: '.',

department: [{
    name:'Basic Ext Layouts',
    expanded: false,
    Maths:[{
        name:'Absolute',
        id:'absolute',
        leaf:true,
    },{
        name:'Accordion',
        id:'accordion',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Anchor',
        id:'anchor',
        leaf:true
    },{
        name:'Border',
        id:'border',
        leaf:true
    }

Comment: Thanks, but again here the "children" comes as a parent node. I want to rename it to several ways like, it can be a department, biology, english. under that i can specify the children nodes as children: 'botony', children: 'zoology'....etc.